# saving mp3 using NAudio LameMP3FileWriter

Tags: mp3, naudio

I'm trying to write 10 sec silence pcm buffer into mp3 file using NAudio LameMP3FileWriter.
The problem is that, final mp3 file duration is not 10 sec. It's smaller.
This is when I open resulting mp3 file using audacity:
[Resulting mp3 in audacity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CykrF.png)

This is my code sample:

```
    private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var fileName = "test.mp3";
        var waveFormat = new WaveFormat(16000, 16, 1);
        var oStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
        using (var writer = new LameMP3FileWriter(oStream, waveFormat, 64))
        {
            var msecs = 10000;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16*2*msecs];
            await writer.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, cts.Token);
        }
     }
```

And this is what I see in explorer(It shows 00:00:09):
[explorer view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNEF2.png)

What should I do to have exactly 10 seconds mp3 file using NAudio LameMP3FileWriter?